# Key is missing data to perform decryption in Laravel 9

Tags: laravel, single-sign-on, saml, laravel-9

I am implementing SSO SAML in Laravel , I am using onelogin package but I have different IDP provider im getting mentioned error Key is missing data to perform decryption after successful login , let me know if any one has faced this issue and overcomed it.

I tried All the packages in internet no one is working fine.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.